# I have a problem when performing a login service with node.js

Tags: c++, node.js, express

I have a problem when performing a login service, I did the test in postman and I don't get the expected result, instead it throws me a "500 Internal Server Error", I really don't know what could be wrong.

auth.js file

```
const router   = require("express").Router(); 
const user     = require("../models/user"); 
const CryptoJS = require("crypto-js"); 
const jwt      = require("jsonwebtoken"); 

//Login Operation
router.post("/login", async (req, res) => {
    try 
    {
      const user = await user.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
      if(!user) return res.status(401).json("Correo o Contraseña incorrectos");
  
      const bytes            = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(user.password, process.env.SECRET_KEY);
      const originalPassword = bytes.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Utf8);
  
      if(originalPassword !== req.body.password) return
      res.status(401).json("Correo o Contraseña incorrectos");
  
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(
        { id: user._id, isAdmin: user.isAdmin },
        process.env.SECRET_KEY,
        { expiresIn: "5d" }
      );
  
      const { password, ...info } = user._doc;
  
      res.status(200).json({ ...info, accessToken });

    }catch(err) 
    {
      res.status(500).json(err);
    }
  });

module.exports = router;
```

index.js file

```
const express  = require("express" );  
const dotenv   = require("dotenv"  ); 
const moongose = require("mongoose");
const app      = express(); 

//Aplication Routes
const authRoute = require("./routes/auth"); 

dotenv.config(); 

moongose
.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URL, {
    useNewUrlParser:    true, 
    useUnifiedTopology: true, 
})
.then(()     => console.log("MongoDB Connection :Active"))
.catch((err) => console.log(err)); 

app.use(express.json()); 

//Use Routes
app.use("/api/auth", authRoute); 

app.listen(8800, () => {
    console.log("Backend Server :Active"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way to understand the error is to log it on the console.

Inside the catch block, insert the following code snippet:

```
console.log("Error Here: " err);
```

This would tell you much more about the error than just its status code.